# India - Are Salary Advances Taxable?

Tags: salary, india, compensation

I work in India and our company has announced salary advances  for people who were affected by a recent natural calamity. Other companies too have announced similar ex-gratia incentives.

It is mentioned that the advance amount will be **recovered** over a period of 12 months starting next financial year.

My question:

> If I avail this advance, will it be taxable , provided that I will be re-paying the amount in monthly installments?

Comment: Don't think of it like a loan, think of it as what it is - an advance. You either get it now and pay tax on it now, or get it in 12 instalments and pay tax on it then.

Answer (score 1):

**The amount is taxable under the Income Tax Department of India.**

However, you might want to confirm the same with the HR of your company, regarding the norms and regulations of the same.